# PostAsync giving 400 bad request C#

Tags: c#, .net, post, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to send a postAsync API using .net by API accept two parameters in body:

1. `scanMethods` JSON object which basically inside will always have the text ['ANTIVIRUS'].
2. a file which the user uploaded.

I am trying to add them in the content with the following code:

```
string json = "{scanMethods: ['ANTIVIRUS'])";
VAR CONTENT = new multipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent(json, UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json"), "scanMethods");
var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream);
content.Add(fileContent, "file", file.fileName);
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

File variable has IFormFile type.
Do I send wrong the parameters to the API?

I expected to get a response from the API, don't know if the issue is the JSON object and I'm inserting it with the wrong way to the API.

I can also see getting `nowritenoseekstreamcontent`.

[image: postman example]

[image: request response]

Comment: You did get a response. It had a status code of 400 Bad Request, which means something about your request was invalid. Did you inspect the post of the response to see if there were any further details? Is the API something that you control - perhaps you could inspect the logs of it or set a breakpoint in order to see what it didn't like about your request?

Comment: @mason i updated my question with the request response, how do i know whats wrong with the request? i dont have access to the logs. Is there any chance i could know from the output whats wrong?

Comment: You provided a screenshot of a browser response. Is this a Blazor app?

Comment: @mason no its a web app having frontend angular and backent .net. teh same response im getting on the backend. im just returning it to the frontend

Comment: They're independent HTTP responses. If you're .NET app on a server is making an HTTP request to some other .NET API, then you wouldn't be able to view those response details in your browser. You need to capture the response body that you got back from making that API call. That's what might have information pertaining to why it believed the request was invalid.

Comment: is your `json` a valid json? i saw unquoted field and non-matching curly brackets.